# Quickly application How to call function from other .py files?

Tags: quickly, programming, modules

I'm new to programing and I'm writing my first python program using quickly.
I have added new window and on this new window I want to call function from main window?
I google for it and all I found is that I nned to import it but it didnt know how.

Here is what I put new window:

```
from magic_ebay.MagicEbayWindow import MagicEbayWindow
```

and I get error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name MagicEbayWindow
```

MagicEbayWindow.py is the name of main window in my program and I want to call function from MagicEbayWindow.py but on other window. ( dont know if it make any sense :) )

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Needs some context.  You could parse parent structures to walk up from a child, pass in a pointer to the class instance (once it's abstracted it's actually a pointer to an instance), or make it a global.  Do you have this in a ppa/github or something?

Comment: no do don't have it on github.

Comment: then you want to be looking at adding to sys.path, but there's not much more i can say without context

Comment: thanks for your help, I will try to drop it to github tonight... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run:

```
from magic_ebay.MagicEbayWindow import MagicEbayWindow
```

You are essentially saying "Please import the `MagicEbayWindow` symbol from the `MagicEbayWindow` module in the `magic_ebay` package".  The error message indicates that your `MagicEbayWindow.py` module doesn't have such a symbol.

There are a few ways you could fix this:

1. Just import the module:

   ```
   from magic_ebay import MagicEbayWindow
   ```

   You can then access functions within the module as e.g. `MagicEbayWindow.foo()`
2. Import individual functions from the module:

   ```
   from magic_ebay.MagicEbayWindow import foo
   ```

   With this style, you can call the functions without the module name prefix.

Comment: Ok I got it finally :)
instead:

Comment: Ok I got it finally :)
instead:
from magic_ebay import MagicEbayWindow
i did:
import MagicEbayWindow
and it work! now when i want to call function from MagicEbayWindow i need to do :
mee = MagicEbayWindow.MagicEbayWindow()
mee.foo(self)

I might doing it all way around but it work for me for now!
THANK YOU!